# Overlaping that cant be fixed with

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

I have a this:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu-li">
        <li class="menu-li with-sublist">
            <a class="left" href="#">A</a>
            <ul class="submenu-list">
                <li><a href="#">A1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A3</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </li>
        <li class="menu-li"><a class="middle" href="#">B</a></li>
        <li class="menu-li"><a class="middle" href="#">C</a></li>
        <li class="menu-li"><a class="right" href="#">D</a></li>
        <li class="clear"><!-- --></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="main-content">
<!-- jquery cycle and more stuff here -->
</div>
```

The `.menu-li` is a horizontal list, `li` elements have `float:left`. So the `.submenu-list` populates vertically and overlaps on the `#main-content` div which contains a jquery cycle slidshow. The problem is that `.submenu-list` appears behind the `#main-content` - obviously I would like it to be displayed over it.

I tried a lot of `z-index` experiments but had no luck. I tend to suspect something else is wrong.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: could you post this on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Could you include your stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever want to use `z-index` dont forget to include `position` either to absolute or relative (and you can't use `float` directly in that element, but you can put another element on the top of this element, eg : http://jsfiddle.net/toopay/xLk8a/)

Comment: position relative in '#header' with a proper z-index in 'submenu-list' made the deal! :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case `z-index` will not work because the `ul.submenu-list` element is contrained by the header element height. You will have to use `position` absolute and then set the `top` and `left` properties of the element dynamically based on the `li` position.